# Can jQuery $('body').click() capture that I have clicked on a nested element which has no class/id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I hope the title makes sense - feel free to edit it if it can be improved.

I have a click function that should return `true` or `false` depending on whether or not I clicked something in a certain list. The list `<ul>` tag has an **id** but the `<li>` units within do not. They also don't have matching classes and don't have any other attributes. They are generated by the server at runtime so I have no way in knowning how many there are going to be (nor should that matter anyway).

What I want to know is how can I verify that a user has clicked on one of them using a **jQuery.click()** function? The logic I'm envisioning is something like:

```
if (clickedElement == "#someList li")
    return true:
```

But I believe this is not possible. **ALSO:** `"#someList li"` is not a static value. This is an argument in the real application and can be like `"#someDiv div"`. Is there a better way to implement this logic? I have attached a fiddle with relevant code: https://jsfiddle.net/6ct245pj/5/

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="someList">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

**JS/jQuery:**

```
$("body").click(function (event) {
    var clickedId = event.target.id;
    var clickedElement = "???";
    //alert(clickedId);

    if (clickedElement == "#someList li") //is it possible to make this true?
    {
        alert("match!!");
    } else {
        alert("no match");
    }

});
```

Comment: if you do $('#someList li').click()... you will have this = the li that was clicked, do you not want to do that for some reason?

Comment: No... It's complicated but I don't need to do any manipulation of the `<li>` element, I just need to know if it was clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use jQuery's [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) function. See the code below using your example:

```
$("body").click(function (event) {
    var clickedId = event.target.id;
    var clickedElement = $(event.target);
    //alert(clickedId);

    if (clickedElement.is("#someList li")) //is it possible to make this true?
    {
        alert("match!!");
    } else {
        alert("no match");
    }

});
```

Comment: Is there a difference between event.target & $(event.target) ?

Comment: `event.target` is a native javascript DOM object (the equivalent of `document.querySelector('#someList li')`). Wrapping it as `$(event.target)` gives the jQuery version (the equivalent of `$('#someList li')`) so that you can use jQuery methods on it.

Comment: SWEET! This worked exactly as I had originally hoped! I didn't think this kind of function was possible! Ty!

Answer (score 2):

Since you are saying the `li` elements are generated and you cannot modify them, test for `tagName`

```js
$("body").click(function(event) {
  var clickedElement = event.target.tagName;

  if (clickedElement == "LI") {
    document.write("match!!");
  } else {
    document.write("no match");
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="someList">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

An alternative you can just attach a click handler to the desired elements themselves. This way, it is guaranteed that the handler will execute for those elements **only**

```js
$("#someList").on('click', 'li', function(event) {
  document.write("match!!");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="someList">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

**Update**

> In otherwords, the #somelist li is an argument in the click handler
>   function

You can put abstract it into a function and bind with a passed selector

```js
function assignHandler(selector) {
  $(selector).on('click', 'li', function(event) {
    document.write("match!!");
  });
}

assignHandler("#someList");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="someList">
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Cool, but is there a way to narrow it further (make sure that it only triggers when it's a child of `someList`)? There are several lists on the page and I don't want it to trigger if they click on a different one

Comment: I can't do that because it might not be `"#someList li"` all the time. Other times it could be the <li> of another list or maybe a `<div>` with no id that is a child of a parent `<div>` that does ( for ex., `"#someDiv div"`). In otherwords, the `#somelist li` is an argument in the click handler function

Answer (score 2):

It's a matter of using the proper selector. `#someList li` refers to the `li` children of `#someList`

HTML:

```
<ul id="someList">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$('body').on('click','#someList li',function() {
    alert('clicked');
});
/* OR, if the `li` elements are not dynamic: */
$('#someList li').click(function() { /* code */ });
```

If you click anywhere else, the `alert` won't be triggered.

http://jsfiddle.net/g4s6wwLa/

Answer (score 0):

You could always try something like this to reiterate through all of the items.

```
$("body").click(function (event) {
    var clickedId = event.target.id;
    var clickedElement = "???";
    //alert(clickedId);

    var list = document.getElementById("someList"); 
    var items = list.getElementsByTagName("li");

    for (var j = 0; j < items.length; ++j) {
        if (list.getElementsByTagName("LI")[j].innerHTML == "item 1") {
            alert("match!!");
        } else {
            alert("no match");
        }
    }
});
```